# Secondary menu disappears when hover ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure how I can go about fixing this exactly but I know it's been done before. If you take a look at [my development site here](http://dev.tintworld.com/), you'll see the issue. When visiting the site, hover over 'Online Store' in the top navigation and it'll show a secondary menu which I'm powering via the code below...

```
jQuery('#menu-main > nav > ul > li:first-child').hover( function () {
   jQuery('#navigation').show();
}, 
function () {
   jQuery('#navigation').hide();
});
```

The problem is of course, trying to access the menu underneath doesn't work because it disappears right away (when going to hover into it).

May someone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: #navigation needs to be a child of #menu-main > nav > ul > li:first-child' or when you go from #menu-main > nav > ul > li:first-child to #navigation you are no longer hovering over the element. Or you need to choose a different event to hide() #navigation on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
jQuery('#menu-main > nav > ul > li:first-child,#navigation').hover( function () {
   jQuery('#navigation').show();
}, 
function () {
   jQuery('#navigation').hide();
});
```

Actually the problem is, You have to add the `target element(the element to be visible)` into the `hover event` collection to achieve your need.